# WooCommerce Product Update Hook

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, webhook

Estoy queriendo resolver la siguiente funcion,

La misma es para que cuando se agregue o actualice un producto esta me lo envie a mi servicio RESTful,

Pero cuando en la condicion filtro por la columna "Post_type == 'product_variation'" la misma me envia los datos completos del producto, cuestion que solo quiero 4 datos relevantes como: "sku", "ID del Padre", "ID del hijo" y "Titulo del Producto",

Tengo el siguiente codigo, el mismo funciona y envia los datos relevantes, pero solamente cuando el producto es "simple"

````
function action_product_add( $new_status, $old_status, $post ){
  // condicionamos si el viejo o nuevo estado es "publicado" y no se encuentra el id, filtre por tipo, en este caso "Producto Variable"
    if( 'publish' != $old_status && 'publish' != $new_status 
        && !empty($post->ID) && !in_array( $post->post_type, array('product') ) ){

        // accedemos a los meta datos del producto
        $sku = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_sku', true);



        // primero obtenemos el id del producto que ya lo hicimos mas arriba
        $product_id = $post->ID;
        // segundo, obtenemos el nombre del producto
        $name = $post->post_title;
        // tercero, obtenemos el id del producto padre
        $parent_id = $post->post_parent;
        // en todo caso usamos el WC_Query para obtener tambien el sku
        $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
        $sku_pro = $product->get_sku(); // obtenemos el sku del producto

         // comenzamos nuestra conexion para trabajar
        $curl = curl_init();

         // llena los campos dentro del array
        $data = array(
        'articulo_maestro' => array( // formamos un array para que dentro de la misma vayan los datos que necesitamos
          'sku_hijo' => $sku, // seleccionamos el sku del producto variable
          'id_hijo' => $product_id, // seleccionamos el id del producto variable
          'id_padre' => $parent_id, // seleccionamos el id del producto padre o maestro
          'name_product' => $name, // seleccionamos el nombre o titulo del producto

            )
        );

        // codificamos los datos a formato json
        $data_string = json_encode($data);
        // procedemos a enviar los datos al servicios rest ful
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => "https://getdata.in/woocommerce/integracion/A76SD56G782G",
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
          CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_string, // los datos que se envia a traves de la solicitud POST
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Content-Type: application/json"
          ),
        ));
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        // cerramos nuestro url de cliente
        curl_close($curl);



    }
} ```


Se podria arreglar para que la funcion envie los datos relevantes incluso cuando el producto sea "variable" ?
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desde Woocommerce 3.x hay dos actions que se disparan al actualizar un producto:

- una para el producto [`woocommerce_update_product`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-data-stores-class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.html#source-view.269)
- una para las variantes de un producto [`woocommerce_update_product_variation`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-data-stores-class-wc-product-variation-data-store-cpt.html#source-view.274)

Si enganchas una función a estas dos actions y filtras por tipo de producto podes obtener toda la info que necesitas, si no le indicas numero de parámetros exponen sólo el id de producto / variation, si le indicas 2 parámetros también te viene el objeto producto/variation y facilita las cosas.

- la función `write_log` es para poder imprimir directamente arrays/objetos en el debug
- para enviar datos a apis en vez de un curl directo por lo general conviene usar [`wp_remote_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_post/) que trae bastante soporte de manejo de errores, proxies, debug, filtrado de response y otras yerbas. ( ref [`wp_http`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_http/) )

```php
/* Cuando cambia un producto
https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-data-stores-class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.html#source-view.269
//*/
add_action(
  'woocommerce_update_product',
  'soes400346_product_or_variation_update',
  10, 2
);

/* Cuando cambia una Variante
https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-data-stores-class-wc-product-variation-data-store-cpt.html#source-view.274
//*/
add_action(
  'woocommerce_update_product_variation',
  'soes400346_product_or_variation_update',
  10, 2
);

function soes400346_product_or_variation_update( $product_id, $product ){
  $product_class = get_class( $product );
  write_log(
    "soes400346_product_or_variation_update {$product_id} {$product_class}"
  );

  $product_type = $product->get_type();
  $product_SKU = $product->get_sku();
  $product_name = $product->get_name();
  $product_parent_id = $product->get_parent_id();

  write_log( "T:{$product_type} SKU:{$product_SKU} N:{$product_name}" );
  write_log( "P_id {$product_parent_id}" );

  switch ( $product_type ) {
    case 'simple' :
    // removemos la action de simple
    remove_action(
      'woocommerce_update_product',
      'soes400346_product_or_variation_update',
      10
    );
    // We'll get here only once!
    write_log( "{$product_id} es Simple" );
    break;

    case 'variable' :
    // removemos la action de variable
    remove_action(
      'woocommerce_update_product',
      'soes400346_product_or_variation_update',
      10
    );
    // We'll get here only once!
    write_log( "{$product_id} es Variable" );
    break;

    case 'variation' :
    // removemos la action de variation
    remove_action(
      'woocommerce_update_product_variation',
      'soes400346_product_or_variation_update',
      10
    );
    // We'll get here only once!
    write_log( "{$product_id} es Variante" );
    break;
  }

  /* send POST json
  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_post/#comment-3495
  //*/

  $endpoint = 'api.example.com';

  $body = [
    'articulo_maestro'  => [
      'sku_hijo' => $product_SKU,
      'id_hijo' => $product_id,
      'id_padre' => $product_parent_id,
      'name_product' => $product_name,
    ],
  ];

  write_log( $body );

  $body = wp_json_encode( $body );

  $options = [
    'method'      => 'POST',
    'body'        => $body,
    'headers'     => [
      'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ],
    'timeout'     => 60,
    'redirection' => 5,
    'blocking'    => true, // false si no hace falta esperar la respuesta
    'data_format' => 'body',
  ];

  $response = wp_remote_post( $endpoint, $options );

}

// https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/260309/62765
if ( !function_exists( 'write_log' ) ) {
  function write_log( $log ) {
    if ( true === WP_DEBUG ) {
      if ( is_array( $log ) || is_object( $log ) ) {
        error_log( print_r( $log, true ) );
      } else {
        error_log( $log );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ¡Funcionó! 

Hice correcciones para agregar mas datos necesarios, y la misma esta funcionando de manera perfecta,

Muchas Gracias por su ayuda !